# Getting "broken pipe" when building Docker image using boot2docker Mac

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, docker

I've followed the guide on http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/mac/ which appears to work ok.

I can run `docker version` and `docker ps` etc but when I go to run a `docker build .` it starts uploading and returns with the message: "write tcp 127.0.0.1:4243: broken pipe" leaving me unable to build.

Comment: Hi I had the same issue only my client was newer, now i'm on 0.12.0 on both sides vut I still get: `$ docker images

2014/06/07 17:00:21 Get http://localhost:4243/v1.12/images/json: EOF`
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged into the VM `boot2docker ssh`, found the debug log at `/var/lib/boot2docker/docker.log` and noticed the first helpful messages:

```
2014/03/22 22:28:57 POST /v1.10/build?rm=1&t=foo
[debug] api.go:942 Warning: client and server don't have the same version (client: 0.9.0, server: 0.8.0)
[error] api.go:959 Error: Multipart upload for build is no longer supported. Please upgrade your docker client.
[error] api.go:91 HTTP Error: statusCode=500 Multipart upload for build is no longer supported. Please upgrade your docker client.
```

So my Mac client (host) Docker was v.9 and the daemon was .8. Not wanting to fiddle with the boot2docker image, I downgraded the client version of Docker to .8 by running:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/docker
cd ~/bin/
curl -o docker https://get.docker.io/builds/Darwin/x86_64/docker-0.8.0
sudo cp ~/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/
```

Then my image built ok.